# Create modal when use onclick event with AJAX

Tags: ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a file, which needs to have 90 modals with lots of long texts, because I need to create a modal when a link is clicked.

***index.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="inc/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="inc/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="inc/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>            
            $(function(){
                $('a').click(function(){
                    var link = $('#name').html(); // I need sent this to my calculator file
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "result.php",
                        type : "post",
                        dataType:"text",
                        data : {
                             name: link
                        },
                        success : function (a){
                            $('#result').html(a);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="result"></div>
        <a href="#" id="name">I need this text for php script</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

***resuilt.php***

```
/* I used PHP becase i need more functions, this only a example how
 * to creat and call a modal after click on a link.
*/
function create_modal($modal_ID = 'myModal')
{
    return "<div class='modal fade' id='$modal_ID' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
                <div class='modal-dialog'>
                  <div class='modal-content'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                      <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button>
                      <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>Nhãn</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>
                      Nội dung
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
                      <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>";
}
echo create_modal();
?>
```

The result is, I need to click on the link two times to show my modal. But it can't close or does anything.

Where did it go wrong? And is there any way to make my idea better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add

```
success : function (a){
                        $('#result').html(a);
                        $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    }
```

just add  $('#myModal').modal('show'); when ajax load your modal in #result

Answer (score 0):

I don't think 90 modals is a good idea.
Try saving data maybe in a databas.
Assign your links different ids.
Use jquery to listen to click events
Get data from your server
Populate modal with values from the server.
 Check this [stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728625/bootstrap-modal-load-data-for-supplied-id).

Let me know if you need help